# Running jar file in command prompt. Java can't find libraries in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar

**EDIT: OK, I think I was being silly. What I really wanted to do was a runnable JAR. I did and now it works.**

So I'm trying to run a little program that interacts with some webpages. The program works fine when I launch it from Eclipse but when I export it to a jar file and try to run it from the command prompt I get this error message:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have the right directory structure for selenium's package name?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming in Eclipse you've added the appropriate libraries to your build path. When you run your program through eclipse, it automatically creates a `java` command including all your libraries in the classpath.

You need to do the same thing

```
java -cp /path/to/libs -jar muzictest.jar
```

Comment: OP's title states (rightfully or wrongly) that his libs **are** in the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: But why isn't the library packaged with the jar? I've never had to do this before (for example with sqlite).

Comment: @spacitron It might be packaged with it, but afaik the default class loader doesn't extract classes from a jar within a jar to put them on the classpath.

Comment: @spacitron How did you build you JAR?

Comment: Used Eclipse's tools. Export>>jar file.